# How to make asynchroneous loader with LoadingCache<K,V>?

Tags: java, caching, asynchronous, guava

The Guava's APIs for [`AbstractLoadingCache`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/AbstractLoadingCache.html) and [`CacheLoader`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheLoader.html) full of words "thread-safe" and "asynchronous".

Unfortunately, I can't deduce from API, how is it possible to create asynchronous postponed loader with it.

For example, they have a sample

```
CacheLoader<Key, Graph> loader = new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
     public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
       return createExpensiveGraph(key);
     }
   };
   LoadingCache<Key, Graph> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build(loader);
```

Now I want to check, if value for some key is contained in cache and, if YES, then draw graph. But if NO, then draw stub, initiate loading and continue to work (GUI). Then, when loading will finish, draw graph.

Is it possible?

Comment: Approximately, `CacheLoader` supports asynchronous _reloading_ -- when a value is already computed, you can have your `Cache` continue to return the old result while the new result is computed asynchronously.  But loading the initial value is done synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to check, if value for some key is contained in cache and, if YES, then draw graph. But if NO, then draw stub, initiate loading and continue to work (GUI).

Use `Cache#getIfPresent` and in case it returns non-`null`, draw it.

Otherwise, draw your stub, start a `Thread` (or better submit a task to some executor) calling `Cache#get`. When it returns, draw the real thing.

Comment: I can do this with `HashMap`. What does `LoadingCache` do then?

Comment: @SuzanCioc As the name says, it does the loading and caching. The loading happens whenever needed without you having to care. But in this case you care, as you don't want to wait for it to happen, which makes it less useful. +++ The caching is the more complicated part, all the expiration and capacity options are rather hard to make yourself. But if you need no loading and no caching, then a map could indeed suffice.